# WebStorm and NX Console for Angular app has another interface than in VS Code?

Tags: angular, console, webstorm, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I installed the NX Console extention in WebStorm (Settings => Plugins => Nx Console Idea and then nx-webstorm plugins).

Then I got:
[image: nx Console Idea]

[image: Nx in WebStorm]

[image: Nx is running on different port]

The question is - is there in WebStorm some little NX pane like in VS Code?:
Or in WebStorm it's just it is that it is?
[image: VS Code Nx Console]

Answer (score 2):

I found its pane in WebStorm aside on the Pane!
[image: nx nrwl console is here in hidden mode]